# Files in a folder are highlighted green with a number 1 next to them. What does this signify?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Yesterday a few files in one of my folders(git repository) have turned green and have a number next to them like so: 
[image]
Can anybody tell me what this means? The repository is synced and up to date and that was the only possible thing I could assume it meant.
Thanks!

Comment: That file has a warning

Comment: The fact that the color was green put that at the bottom of things I was looking for. That fixed it, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Those are the file explorer's problem decorations. They use colors and indicators to show which files have problems associated with them. The green here indicates there is a warning in the file, and the `1` indicates that there is one warning.

You can disable these by [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings): `"problems.decorations.enabled": false`

Comment: Warnings would normally be yellow. Green means tracked and with changes since the last Git commit. It seems green overrides yellow.

Answer (score 6):

This works well if you are using git. Doing a simple commit to your repo will take the warnings away.

I am using SVN external to VS code for a project and it became quite frustrating seeing files with issues and 'untracked'.

If anyone else in in this boat, set `"git.enabled": false` in your vs code workspace settings.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for this. I've finally figured out the answer.

Go to File>Preferences>Settings (also ctrl + ,)

Go tot he "Workspace" tab > Git. Set Decorations Enabled: Off
[image: Settings>Workspace>Git>Decorations Enabled: Off]

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of git version control, the green color means the file is not completely added to git git repository not commited.
if you dont want that project just delete it.