# Git changing to another branch and not bringing previous branch changes with me?

Tags: git

I was working on branch-A, made code changes in a new folder, committed and pushed to origin.

Now I switched to branch-B (git checkout branch-B) and pulled from origin (git pull origin branch-B). However, the new folder that I made in branch-A appears in green on the file explorer (I'm using VScode) and there are 10 uncommited change in my VScode source control.

Now I'm afraid to make any commits to branch-B as it will include these new files I created on branch-A.

I would like to work on branch-B without carrying over changes I previously made to branch-A.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Doesn't sound right to me. There must be something else wrong. Would you mind going into a bit more details?

Comment: Check your `.gitignore` file. Is it the same in both branches?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if there were a `.git` folder inside that new folder: it would be treated as a nested git repository, which might not be what you wanted.

Removing the nested `.git` subfolder, then adding/committing ([as I mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60769296/6309)) should be enough.

---

The [green+number could be a way to mention warning associated with the content of that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495322/6309).
So if there was no nested `.git`, that would simply mean that the new folder, when compiled in the context of your branch `B`, has warnings.