# How to treat nested repository (submodule) like a normal directory?

Tags: git, git-submodules

My Wordpress site is version-controlled with Git, including the `wp-content/plugins/` folder. Now there is a plugin (wp-editormd) that comes with its own Git repository, `wp-content/plugins/wp-editormd/vendor/jaxsonwang/wp-settings-api-class/` (with `.git/` inside) . Git treats it as a submodule, which is undesired. I am worried that Git-ignoring it could break the plugin or the plugin's update mechanism. How can I tell Git that it should treat the directory like a normal directory?

Comment: Just remove the .git folder and control it via maim project repo

Comment: I am worried this might break something.

Comment: Shouldn't brrak anything, have had similar situation many times and this step helped

Comment: Alternatively change the .git folder name, and  check if works

Comment: OK, I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I am worried this might break something

The only thing it break is the history inside the submodule folder, which will be gone.

If it is a submodule (recorded in the `.gitmodules`), a [`git submodule deinit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309) is in order.

If not, a `git rm SubmoduleFolder` first, (no trailing `/`), is enough, in order to remove the [gitlink (special entry in the index)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/1.8.3#_description), as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371742/6309).

If it was not added, simply removing the nested `.git` folder is enough.

Then you can add, commit and push that folder, as a regular one.

Comment: I may misunderstand you. But the main Git project (my wordpress install) has no knowledge of the `SubmoduleFolder` yet, so there is no `.gitmodules` entry or gitlink. Only when I `git add --all` will Git warn about "adding embedded git repository" and then treat it as such.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein No submodule: good. But you still need `git rm SubmoduleFolder` first, (no trailing `/`) to remove the reference to the nested git repository (because if the nested `.git/` folder): even without a .gitmodules, Git would still treat it as a "gitlink", a reference to another repository root tree.

Comment: If I `git rm SubmoduleFolder` before `git add --all`, I get `fatal: pathspec 'SubmoduleFolder' did not match any files`. If I do it afterwards, I get `fatal: could not lookup name for submodule 'SubmoduleFolder'`. If I `git rm --cached SubmoduleFolder` afterwards, I get `error: the following file has staged content different from both the file and the HEAD: SubmoduleFolder`. I can force removal, but then `SubmoduleFolder/**/*` will not be version-controlled.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein Sure: just deleted the nested .git folder, and Git will treat it as a regular folder. I have edited the answer accordingly.